# How can I get info from user with OptionParser in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, optparse

For example, when I type `ruby file.rb -a "water the plants"` in command line
I want this line to be added on a hash. Such as a to-do list.
So it will look something like `item1: water the plants`
Here's what I did so far:

```
require 'optparse'

option_parser = OptionParser.new do |opts|
    opts.on '-a', '--add', 
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Look a bit more closely at the examples in the docs for [OptionParser](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html).

To accept a *value* for an argument, you have to specify it in the second argument to `opts.on`, something like this:

```
require 'optparse'
option_parser = OptionParser.new do |opts|
    opts.on '-a', '--add val' do |value|
      puts value
    end
end.parse!
```

To make it a required argument, just change that `val` to capitalized `VAL` (it can be any word, I'm just using "val" as an example).

Calling it, you can see how it works:

```
ruby file.rb -a "water the plants"
# => "water the plants"

ruby file.rb -a "water the plants" "do the dishes"
# => "water the plants"

ruby file.rb -a "water the plants" -a "do the dishes"
# => water the plants
# => do the dishes
```

As you can see, to pass multiple values, you need to include the `-a` flag multiple times. The block is called for each value individually.